# Quotients of subspaces of $C(\alpha)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A well known problem, attributed to H. P. Rosenthal, asks whether or not every quotient of $C(\alpha)$, $\alpha$ countable ordinal, is $c_0$-saturated. As it is known, $C(\alpha)$ are $c_0$-saturated and also every quotient of $C(\alpha)$ contains $c_0$. Since a closed subspace of a quotient is a quotient of a closed subspace one may ask the following.

**Question I.** Let $X$ be a closed subspace of $C(\alpha)$. Is every quotient map $Q:X\to X/Y$ not strictly singular ? In particular what is the answer when $X/Y\cong c_0$ ?

This is formally a stronger question than the initial problem and has a positive answer when $X=C(\alpha)$. A possible negative answer indicates that the problem probably also has a negative answer. Moreover, the above question has a negative answer if the following has a positive one.

**Question II.** Does there exist a universal constant $C$ such that for every equivalent norm $|\|\cdot\||$ on $c_0$, there exists a countable ordinal $\alpha$ such that $(c_0,|\|\cdot\||)$ is $C$-isomoprhic to a subspace of $C(\alpha)$ ?

Comment: Do you know the answer to Question 1 when $X$ is the Schreier space (or, more generally, when $X$ has an unconditional basis)?

Comment: No I do not know. But I really concern for Question II. Is it possible Zippin's work to be related to that question?

Comment: Nice question. My initial thoughts. The answer to Q2 should be negative. The collection of renormings of $c_0$ is analytic, and so you can cook up a universal space for the property in the question that doesn't contain $C[0,1]$. In some sense (this isn't precise, since the universal space need not be  $C(\alpha)$) this implies there is a countable $\alpha$ for all renormings, which shouldn't be true.

Comment: Is it possible to show that if for every specific equivalent norm there exists an $\alpha$ such that  $C_0$  with this norm embeds into $C(\alpha)$ with a universal constant $C$ then there exists a countable ordinal $\beta$ such that   $C(\beta)$ is universal for all these embeddings?

Comment: @ Spyridon Argyros I don't know. This goes back to your work with Dodos. But actually we may not need it. For all $n$ renorm $c_0$ so that every $n$ subset of the basis is, say, 2-equivalent to $\ell_1^n$. Now take an $\alpha$ where all of these $C$-embed into $C(\alpha)$. Continue this process (need to think more how to do this) to increase the $\ell_1$-index of some $C(\alpha)$ spaces. Then take the universal space $X$. Since $\ell_1$ does not embeds into any $C(\alpha)$'s, by the universal space construction it doesn't embed into $X$ either but the $\ell_1$ index of $X$  is $\omega_1$.

Comment: @Bunyamin Sari Just to understand. You claim that every universal space should contain $\ell_1$ ?

Comment: @ Spyridon Argyros If the above construction works we get: for all $\beta$ there exists a $(c_0,|.|_{\beta})$ for which $\ell_1$-index is greater than $\beta$ and $C$-embeds into some $C(\alpha_{\beta})$. So the universal space $X$ (constructed by [AD]) for the collection $C(\alpha_{\beta})$ should not contain $\ell_1$ but $X$ contain $\ell_1$ since the $\ell_1$ index is uncountable.

Comment: Actually, just realized the above construction is not possible. You can't get a renorming of $c_0$ with large $\ell_1$-index.

Comment: I agree with you. According to Dodos - Ferenczi (Fundamenta Mathematicae. 2007. , v.193, p.171 - 179) the spaces with separable dual are strongly bounded

Comment: @ Bill Johnson I. Gasparis informed me that  Ted Odell  ( arXiv:math/9201219) has proved that the quotients of the Schreier  space are $c_0$ saturated and also the quotient map is not strictly singular.